How to know which UV channel a USDZ model file is using in SceneKit?
So I have an FBX model file and its texture. The texture works fine when I set it in Apple's Reality Converter:

Then I export the model to USDZ format, without the texture (because multiple models share the same texture file, so I want to save space by having separate USDZ and texture files).
When I add it in SceneKit, I notice the color is off:

It turns out that I have to set the UV channel to 1 (rather than the default 0):
node.geometry?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.mappingChannel = 1

After this, the color is shown correctly:

However, in my case, some models use channel 0, while others use channel 1. I don't know how to tell it. This information is definitely available to Reality Converter because it renders the color correctly for all of my models.
You can download my sample project here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GTvDLD-hsOgv_vEfKMgXEMUXWhZzE53D/view?usp=sharing
The sample project contains the USDZ and texture. I also put FBX there which is not used in code, but you can play around with it in Reality Converter.

It seems during the convert process, this information about the mapping channel is lost, or is misinterpreted from the original FBX in some way. When I convert the USDZ to SCN, in the SCN the texture is wrong. then setting the channel to 1 it is correct. btw: when I compile the App, I only see a white screen with nothing rendered.

@ZAY ya i probably setup the camera wrongly, so need to go to view hierarchy UI debugger.

is there a workaround to this? otherwise i would have to manually group my 500+ assets by the uv channel, which is unrealistic.

I currently have no idea how you could probably identify the right channel. From my understanding, you convert all of your models to USDZ in a first step. by doing this, you get some wrong channel (or all re-set to 0). So it will be not easy to determine, which channel is right. because both seems to produce some texture. but only one of the channels is the correct one. hard to make some mechanism to identify this, without manually set each one of the models. If I come up with some solution I'll let you know. Happy New Year.
